# Identify index of all elements in a list comparing with another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance I have a list `A`:

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 200, 400, 500, 600, 400, 700, 200, 500, 800]
```

And I have list `B`:

```
B = [100, 200, 200, 500, 600, 200, 500]
```

I need to identify the index of elements in `B` with comparison to `A`

I have tried:

```
list_index = [A.index(i) for i in B]
```

It returns:

```
[0, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5]
```

But what I need is:

```
[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Gonna need to write more code.  You'll want to keep track for each value what the latest index you've "used" is, and for the next occurrence of the value take the index after that one.

Comment: Do you mean `[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]`, i.e., use every element in A only once? And what would you expect for, e.g. `[500, 200]`?

Comment: @Nyps for [500,200] it must return [5,9]

Comment: What if one of them is not included or not in the correct order? e.g. `x = [800, 200, 500]` or `y = [200, 500, 900]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can iterate through the enumeration of `A` to keep track of the indices and yield the values where they match:

```
A = [100,200,300,200,400,500,600,400,700,200,500,800]
B = [100,200,200,500,600,200,500]

def get_indices(A, B):
    a_it = enumerate(A)
    for n in B:
        for i, an in a_it:
            if n == an:
                yield i
                break
            
list(get_indices(A, B))
# [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

This avoids using `index()` multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this. Move over both lists and append the index when they are equal:

```
A = [100,200,300,200,400,500,600,400,700,200,500,800]

B = [100,200,200,500,600,200,500]

i, j = 0, 0
list_index = []
while j < len(B):
    if B[j] == A[i]:
        list_index.append(i)
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(list_index)
```

Output:

`[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list called indices, and get the first index into it. Then iterate rest of the items in `B`, then take the slice of `A` from the last index in `indices` list and get the index of the item, add it to the last index + 1, then append it back to the `indices` list.

```py
indices = [A.index(B[0])]
for i,v in enumerate(B[1:]):
    indices.append(A[indices[-1]+1:].index(v)+indices[-1]+1)


#indices: [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would use:

```py
A=[100,200,300,200,400,500,600,400,700,200,500,800]
B=[100,200,200,500,600,200,500]

list_index = []
removedElements = 0

for i in B:
  indexInA = A.index(i)
  A.pop(indexInA)
  list_index.append(indexInA+removedElements)
  removedElements+=1

print(list_index)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A = np.array([100,200,300,200,400,500,600,400,700,200,500,800])
B = [100, 200, 200, 500, 600, 200, 500]

idx = np.arange(len(A))
indices = {i: idx[A == i].tolist() for i in set(B)}
[indices[i].pop(0) for i in B]
```

Answer (score 1):

I loop through B and set the checked index to None in A. Thus the code will alter A.

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 200, 400, 500, 600, 400, 700, 200, 500, 800]
B = [100, 200, 200, 500, 600, 200, 500]

res = []
for i in B:
    res.append(A.index(i))
    A[A.index(i)] = None

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```